# React Error when updating useQuery variable

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have a query that takes the userId as one of its variables.

The userId is being acquired from a context at the root.

```
const { activeUser } = useContext("Context");

 const { loading, data } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: { userId: activeUser },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });
```

The initial render is fine, however when I try to query for a new active user,
I simply update the activeUser in the root context.

I get this error:

`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render'). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Even though an error is thrown, the query seems to be working and fetching.

I'm not sure where this error is occuring.

Comment: The problem here is, probably, not because of the above code but rather due to changing the state somewhere in your render function.

Comment: This code is fine.

Comment: @ManavM If I have multiple components that change state depending on the same variable, then how should I structure code so that re-renders are not conflicting?

Is there some sort of callback function, or could it be the order of useEffect?

Comment: @Henry "Change state depending on same variable" would make them derived states and it's ok to put that code in your render function. What I meant is that you should never do a `setState` in your render function or run a state setter (that you get from React.useState) inside the body of your functional component. In case of function components, state modification should only happen inside hooks or functions that are not directly called inside the body.